# Do sub-classes share static variables of parent class in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are static members inherited? (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c)

If I have a parent class (`Base`) and it has a static `std::map`, do `Base` and `Base`'s children all share the same `std::map`? If not, how can I make them share it?

Comment: Did you think to ... try it and see?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c

Comment: @Gnawme: That is the same question.

Comment: No. It is the *exact* same question d by the exact same person with the exact same answers. That is not a different question.

Comment: So Keand64 and Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh are the same person?

Comment: I guess it all depends on what *share* means to you. As a matter of fact not only derived classes, but *all* code in your program *shares* the same static variables...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they all share it:

```
class A {
protected:
    static std::map<int,int> x;

public:
    static void push(int a, int b) { x[a] = b; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    static int size() { return x.size(); }
};

int main() {
    A::push(5,3);
    A::push(4,2);
    std::cout << B::size() << "\n";  // Displays "2"
}
```

Unless, of course, one of the child classes declares its own member variable with the same name, in which case the base class version will be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Static member variables are there once per class. Why should this somehow change when there is a class deriving from it? That is, all derived classes share the base's static member's.

Comment: So if I add the pair `"foo"->"bar"`, that change will be shared between the children?

Comment: If you add this to a static member in the base class: yes.

Answer (score 1):

You make the unqualified name in the derived class find the parent implementation by not doing anything to hide it.  If you had a member with that name redefined in the derived class, then that would be found instead of the parent's static member.