# Derived class Needs variables to be redefined which are there pure abstract base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question regarding Pure abstract base class. Suppose i have an abstract pure base class with some functions and variables. If i create 2 derived classes from the base, do both the derived classes get their own set of variables?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base
{
public: 
virtual void display() = 0;
protected: 
static input;
static output;
}

class Derived1:public base
{
public:
virtual void display();
void readInput();
}

class Derived2:public base
{
public:
virtual void display();
void readInput();
}
class Derived1:public base
{
virtual void display();
}
int main()
{
 Derived1 obj1;
 Derived2 obj2;

return 0;
}
```

So here obj1 and obj2 get 2 sets variables "input" and "output" individually? Or is there only going to be 1 set?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are static members inherited? (C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c)

Answer (score 4):

They will have just One set of static variables for all the derived classes. It's very easy to test:

```
class Base
{
public:
    static int k;
};
int Base::k;

class Derived1: public Base
{

};
class Derived2: public Base
{

};

int main(){
    Derived1::k = 5;
    Derived2::k = 10;

    std::cout << Derived1::k << "   " << Derived2::k;
}
```

output: `10    10`

The reason is that all static stuff applies to the base class alone (note that they are bound to the *class*, not to an *object*, so it's also irrelevant to the number of objects of each class created). Since you have just one base class, it doesn't matter how many derived ones you will have, the set of the variables will still be bound to that single base one.

Answer (score 2):

Although you can easily test this, here's a hint: consider how you **define** the member:

```
int base::input;
```

and now think there's only one `base` class, and `static` binds to the class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sets of variables; one for `obj 1` and one for `obj 2`.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables are shared between class instances (including derived class instances).

Comment: Base is pure abstract class, it cant be instantiated, so means we cant sue those variables from the base class. 

also a class would be pure abstract class if any of its method is pure virtual.. Can we have the base class with some of the methods pure virtual and few them with the methods implemented in base class?

Comment: @Fancier Yes of course you can implement methods in your abstract class. Try it.