# Are static members inherited?

Tags: c++

I have a static member variable in class A and class B derives from class A.

```
class A
{
  public:
    A()
    {
      a = 3;
    }
    static int a;
};

int A::a = 0;

class B : public A
{
  public:
    B()
    {
      a = 4;        
    }
};

void main()
{
  A objA;
  cout << "Before:" << A::a;
  B obj;
  cout << endl << "After:" << A::a;
}
```

As per [Are static fields inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c/998298#998298) when derived type object is made then it also creates base type.
I have following questions:

1. How is it that instead of `A::a` I can also access `objA.a`? Static variables shouldn't be accessible through objects of that class.
2. If for derived class also a new static variable is made (specific to `class B`) then why is it not necessary to initialize the static variable for `class B`?
3. Why does the output of following shown as:

> Before:3
>
> After:4

When it is expected to show 3 for before and after?

Comment: The answer to the title depends on what your definition for the term *inherited* is.

Answer (score 4):

The access to the static variable is what is inherited. Do note that static members with private access will not be accessible, as that is what the `protected` keyword is for.

Comment: But is this the answer to the problem that is asked ?

Comment: @user2287617: This is the answer to the question asked in the title, but not to the three loosely related questions in the body.

Comment: This is simply wrong.  Private or not, _all_ members are inherited.

Answer (score 3):

1. There's not objA.a, there's access to a inside B() constructor where A::a is visible and thus can be accessed as just "a".
2. B::a refer to the same address in memory, there's no new static variable for B::a, it's same which you can check via &B::a.
3. It is not expected to be 3 and 3, it is expected to be 3 and 4 because line "B obj;" changes A::a value, and because of (2) it's same variable as B::a (i.e. B() constructor changes A::a).

Comment: You can indeed access the variable using `objA.a`.

Answer (score 2):

Your fundamental problem is that you have mis-interpreted the answers in the question to which you linked. When you derive the class `B` you **do not** make a new static variable `a`.

So, `A::a` and `B::a` are the same variable. Once you correct this mis-understanding everything else will be obvious and clear.

Looking at your code:

```
A objA; //A() executes which sets A::a to 3
cout << "Before:" << A::a; //outputs 3
B obj; //now B() executes and sets B::a to 4
cout << endl << "After:" << A::a; //outputs 4 since A::a is same variable as B::a
```

---

> How is it that instead of A::a I can also access objA.a?

Because the language specification says that you can. The language specification says that `A::a` and `objA.a` are the same variable. This is covered in any good guide to the language. For example, online you can read [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) which says it like this:

> To refer to a static member n of class T, two forms may be used: qualified name T::m or member access expression e.m or e->m, where e is an expression that evaluates to T or T* respectively. When in the same class scope, the qualification is unnecessary.

Comment: Please note im not using B::a, its A::a in both the cases that i am using.

Comment: Also note that new static variable would be created refer to the link which proves it.

Comment: Exactly -- there is no `B::a`, there is only Zuul..no wait, there is only `A::a` (sorry, @david-heffernan 's avatar gave me flashbacks of Ghostbusters)

Comment: @user2287617 No, there is no new static variable. `A::a` and `B::a` are one and the same thing. Once you understand that, you will be fine.

Comment: Good. You should accept an answer. Choose the one that you think is best.

Answer (score 0):

1. Static variables are accessible through objects of that class.  Why wouldn't they be?
2. There is only one copy of any static variable.  If another class inherits it, it only gets access to the same static variable, not another copy.
3. Because `B::B()` changed `A::a` to 4.  Both `B` and `A` share access to `A::a`.

Answer (score 0):

> Are static members inherited?

In the sense that static members of the base class are also static members of any derived class, yes.

> How is it that instead of `A::a` i can also access `objA.a`. Static variables shouldnt be accessible through objects of that class.

That's just how the language is defined. Both are equivalent, and the object style can be more convenient if you can't easily write the type of the object.

> If for derived class also a new static variable is made (specific to class B) then why is it not necessary to initialize the static variable for class B?

There isn't a new static variable specific to class `B`; there's just one for class `A`. The inheritance means that it is also scoped within class `B`; but `A::a` and `B::a` both refer to the same variable.

> Why does the output of following shown as [3,4] when it is expected to show 3 for Before and after?

As described above, there is only one variable, and the constructor of `B` sets it to `4`.

Comment: Concerning the use of object style: something like `this->a` (instead of just `a`) can be useful in templates, to make the variable name dependent.