# How inherit static members?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static

I am struggling to make my derived class inherit static members as I would like.

```
class Base
{
public:
    static int member;
};

class Derived : Base
{
};

Derived::member = 2;
Base::member = 0;
```

Therefore: `Derived::member == 0;`

How do I implement a pattern where `Derived::member == 2` ?

Comment: By declaring `static int member` on `Derived` as well. Although of course that's a bad solution to a problem that probably does not exist.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998247/are-static-members-inherited-c)

Comment: It doesn't seem very "object orientated" to declare the same static variable in every class that is derived from Base.

Answer (score 1):

Static members cannot be inherited because they belong to the class declaring them (because they are actually just global variables with some more advanced access), but your derived class can still access them without having to write `Base::` (of course they have to be atleast `protected`). Access also means that you can set them.

Answer (score 0):

You can not inherit static member variables of a base class as they belong to class not an just an specific instance of a class. So all base and derived class (As well as their instances) will share the same static member variable, and any change in it will be seen by all base and derived class (And also by their instances.)